# Android Firebase Analytics not Working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I followed the instructions at [Firebase Analytics quick start](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/), but even after 24 hours, no user session was registered at [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com).

I know that my `google-services.json` is correct because [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users) is working properly (both Google and Facebook users are visible on the dashboard).

My Gradle dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Could you try using the instructions here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#log_events) to get more detailed logs on what is happening?

Comment: @hatboysam https://gist.github.com/jpventura/c3bcf54feb7c4b7ab0985c07964ce1aa

Comment: There does not seem to be any issue with Firebase Analytics on the device here, are you looking at the app 'com.startup.android' in the console?

Answer (score 2):

[At August, 1st 2016, Google Developers upgraded Firebase quickstart examples on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/commit/df1be1350022020c428736c6c8f147ac2ec1e23c)

Firebase version was upgraded from 9.2.1 to 9.4.0, which seems to have fixed my Analytics update issues.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem what i missed in my project gradle file add this dependency

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

and in my android gradle or you can say app gradle i add this
in last line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```